# Pansharpening ALL(8) worldview 3 and worldview 2 bands

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, satellite, pansharpening, worldview-2

Trying to pansharpen all the bands instead of just the R,G,B,NIR bands in worldview-2 and -3 imagery.

ArcGIS Pro only has inputs for those previously mentioned bands in the pansharpening tool. Is there a way to properly pansharpen all the bands? Or do I break it up separately and then pansharpen the remaining four bands pretending that they are RGBNIR and not Cirrus, Yellow, RedEdge, NIR2 as inputs?

also is this even technically "allowed"? Since the pan band only stretches over a certain wavelength.

Answer (score 1):

Think I solved it. If you add the WV2 data to a mosaicked dataset and use "Pansharpen and Multispectral" Processing Template it looks like it sharpens all of the bands